# Can't get Blazor project running with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, .net-standard, blazor

I'm trying to create a simple Blazor client server app using EF, similar to [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1244729/ASP-NET-Core-Blazor-CRUD-using-Entity-Framework-an).

So I've got a client, server, and common libraries, and this worked fine. But then I added the EF component to the common library, so that I could use real data from my database, instead of toy data from the demo.

I tried making them all Core 3.0, but this doesn't work because Blazor seems to require .NET Standard 2.0. Without that, I get all kinds of errors.

But then the common library can't use EF, because (if I'm reading this right)  [EF6 isn't supported on Standard 2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/271). If I try, I again get tons of errors.

So I'm not sure, but I can't find any scenario that would allow me to share EF objects between client and server--which is a major rationale for Blazor.

Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shared library should not use or reference EF.

Add EF to the Server project only and make the data available through an API controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the common project netstandard and use EF core (not EF 6)

Comment: This won't compile; I get linker errors trying to consume EF Core from a netstandard project.

Comment: I have this working. Do not use EF Core also in the common lib (that is used by blazor, that won't work). Only use EF references on the server side.